# My code for removing url filters does not work

Tags: javascript, database, url, frontend

I am trying to implement a function that enables me to delete filters passed via URL.

For example if my ural is the following:

"&data=true&filterList=include|value|Location|Region|Europe|Asia;include|value|Time|Current+Month+Flag|1;include|value|Employee|Employee+Type|Employee;&decimals=5;"

And I wopuld like to delete **Employee** the output should be this:

"&data=true&filterList=include|value|Location|Region|Europe|Asia;include|value|Time|Current+Month+Flag|1;&decimals=5;"

This is due to Employee being the only filter applied for the **include|value|Employee** subject area

I have added a code snippet of my function and the expected outputs I am trying to achieve.

```js
function deleteUrlSection(url, key, deleteValue) {
  const sections = url.split(';');
  let updatedSections = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
    let section = sections[i];
    let keyIndex = section.indexOf(key);
    if (keyIndex !== -1) {
      let values = section.substring(keyIndex).split('|');
      let updatedValues = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < values.length; j++) {
        if (values[j] !== deleteValue) {
          updatedValues.push(values[j]);
        }
      }
      if (updatedValues.length > 0) {
        updatedSections.push(updatedValues.join('|'));
      }
    } else {
      updatedSections.push(section);
    }
  }
  return updatedSections.join(';');
}

//test 1
let url = "&data=true&filterList=include|value|Location|Region|Europe|Asia;include|value|Time|Current+Month+Flag|1;include|value|Employee|Employee+Type|Employee;&decimals=5;";
let key = "Region";
let deleteV = "Asia";
console.log("New Url ", "", deleteUrlSection(url, key, deleteV));

//expected output 
//&data=true&filterList=include|value|Location|Region|Europe;include|value|Time|Current+Month+Flag|1;include|value|Employee|Employee+Type|Employee;&decimals=5;


//test 2
let url2 = "&data=true&filterList=include|value|Location|Region|Europe;include|value|Time|Current+Month+Flag|1;include|value|Employee|Employee+Type|Employee;&decimals=5;";
let key2 = "Region";
let deleteV2 = "Europe";
console.log("New Url2 ", "", deleteUrlSection(url2, key2, deleteV2));

//expected output 
//&data=true&filterList=include|value|Time|Current+Month+Flag|1;include|value|Employee|Employee+Type|Employee;&decimals=5;


//test 3
let url3 = "&data=true&filterList=include|value|Location|Region|Europe|Asia;include|value|Time|Current+Month+Flag|1;include|value|Employee|Employee+Type|Employee;&decimals=5;";
let key3 = "Current+Month+Flag";
let deleteV3 = "1";
console.log("New Url3 ", "", deleteUrlSection(url, key3, deleteV3));

//expected output 
//&data=true&filterList=include|value|Location|Region|Europe|Asia;include|value|Employee|Employee+Type|Employee;&decimals=5;
```

**Further issue explanation:**

The formatting for the filters is as follows:

**include|value|Location|Region|Europe|Asia**

=>

**include | value | subjectArea | key | filter1 | filter2** ...|...

i.e : *each item in the filterList can have multiple filters e.g. Filter1,Filter2...*

There may be instances where one of the Filters is the same as the subjectArea however only the filter should be deleted - unless it is the only filter present, in this case the whole filterList item containing that filter should be deleted.

Im basically identifying the filterList item via the key (found after the 3rd pipe "|" and then deleting filters which start after the key and 4th Pipe. If only one filter exist delete the whole item containing that key and filter )

Comment: `let key3 = "Current+Month+Flag";
let deleteV3 = "1";` does not match your expected output

Comment: @mplungjan this is the issue I am having, I don't know how to get this desired output

Comment: The code seems to work when there is more than one Filter as seen in Test 1.
However, If there is only one item after the 4th | the whole filterList item that matched the key provided should be deleted. Yet in test 2 and 3 the key is left as part of the URL even though there is only the filter specified for deletion in the item

Comment: Your EXPECTED output in test 3 does not match what you want to happen. I would expect the EXPECTED output to be `"&data=true&filterList=include|value|Location|Region|Europe|Asia;include|value|Employee|Employee+Type|Employee;&decimals=5;";`

Comment: It is impossible to know that `include|value|Location|` is actually `include|value|Location|Region` unless you map the keys. Do you have a `include|value|Location|City` too ?

Comment: @mplungjan ah sorry and thank you. I didn't spot this. I have now changed this in the example above and provided a further explanation to what and How I'm trying to achieve. We basically ignore : a | b | c | as we only delete things based on the key and Filter provided

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that works with

```
include | value | subjectArea | key | filter1 | filter2 ...|...
```

Note the key in test #4 is "Employee type" and not "Employee" according to your comments

```js
// include | value | subjectArea | key | filter1 | filter2 ...|...
const consoleKeyColor = "color: blue; font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;";


const findInArray = (filterArray, keyValueArray) => keyValueArray.every(r => filterArray.includes(r));
const deleteUrlSection = (searchString, key, deleteValue) => {
  const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(searchString);
  const filterList = searchParams.get("filterList");
  const sections = filterList.split(';');
  const newSections = [];
  sections.forEach((section, i) => {
    if (section === "") { // keep the trailing semicolon
      newSections.push("");
      return
    }
    const parts = section.split('|');
    const firstPart = parts.slice(0, 4).join("|"); // includes the key
    let [filterKey, ...values] = parts.slice(3);
    if (filterKey !== key || !values.includes(deleteValue)) {
      newSections.push(section); // neither key nor value found
    } else {
      console.log("Processing", filterKey, "- values", values.join(', '))    
      values = values.filter(value => value !== deleteValue);
      console.log(
        `Removed %c${deleteValue}`, consoleKeyColor, `from ${section}. Values left: ${values.join(", ")}`)
      if (values.length > 0) { // still values
        newSections.push(firstPart + "|" + values.join("|"));
      } else console.log(filterKey, "deleted")
    }
  });
  console.log("%cNew:\n", consoleKeyColor, newSections.join(";"))
  searchParams.set("filterList", newSections.join(";"))

  return searchParams.toString()
};

const URLs = [
 "&data=true&filterList=include|value|Location|Region|Europe|Asia;include|value|Time|Current+Month+Flag|1;include|value|Employee|Employee+Type|Employee;&decimals=5;",
 "&data=true&filterList=include|value|Location|Region|Europe;include|value|Time|Current+Month+Flag|1;include|value|Employee|Employee+Type|Employee;&decimals=5;"
];

const tests = [{
    title: "Remove Asia",
    key: "Region",
    deleteValue: "Asia",
    url: URLs[0],
    expected: "&data=true&filterList=include|value|Location|Region|Europe;include|value|Time|Current+Month+Flag|1;include|value|Employee|Employee+Type|Employee;&decimals=5;"
  },
  {
    title: "Remove Europe and then delete region",
    key: "Region",
    deleteValue: "Europe",
    url: URLs[1],
    expected: "&data=true&filterList=include|value|Time|Current+Month+Flag|1;include|value|Employee|Employee+Type|Employee;&decimals=5;"
  },
  {
    title: "Remove Current Month Flag and then Time",
    key: "Current Month Flag",
    deleteValue: "1",
    url: URLs[0],
    expected: "&data=true&filterList=include|value|Location|Region|Europe|Asia;include|value|Employee|Employee+Type|Employee;&decimals=5;"
  },
  {
    title: "Remove Employee value and then Employee",
    key: "Employee Type",
    deleteValue: "Employee",
    url: URLs[0],
    expected: "&data=true&filterList=include|value|Location|Region|Europe|Asia;include|value|Time|Current+Month+Flag|1;&decimals=5;"
  }
];

tests.forEach(({ title, key, deleteValue, url, expected }, i) => {
  console.log(`\n--------- Test ${i+1}: ${title} - key: %c${key} ---------`, consoleKeyColor);
  const result = deleteUrlSection(url, key, deleteValue);
  expected = `${new URLSearchParams(expected).toString()}`;
  console.assert(result === expected, `Result and expected\n${result}\n${expected}`);
})
```

```html
Please open console using F12 or Inspect to see results
```

Comment: thank you for the help. Unfortunately this does not work, if you look at the result for test 1 as we have only removed Asia the remaining filter should be **include%7Cvalue%7CRegion%7CEurope but we are missing the Region. Also what is findInArray?

Comment: It actually looks to work perfect apart from removing the key when there is more than one filter as mentioned above

Comment: I needed to change to  `const firstPart = parts.slice(0, 3).join("|");` to keep the first 3 strings.

Comment: I think I fixed this issue by changing const firstPart = parts.slice(0, 2).join("|"); to const firstPart = parts.slice(0, 4).join("|");

I made a slight mistake in the comment above when specifying that it should be include%7Cvalue%7CRegion%7CEurope, it should actually be Locationinclude%7Cvalue%7CLocation%7CRegion%7CEurope. We were therefore missing Both Location and region

Comment: that is correct, so we want to keep the whole first section if there are any filters left after the deleted one. eg: include|value|Location|Region|Europe 
If we were to now delete Europe we would remove the whole thing eg (include|value|Location|Region|Europe)
as the deleted filter is the only one

Comment: Hi @Jakub97 - I updated the script to work as specified and added a set of tests to test that it works. If the output is not as expected, it will be due to error in the spec and not the code ;)